# Event handlers not working correctly in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

Trying to make a jsfiddle so I can post it on here and get some help with a problem; however, I'm having a problem getting jsfiddle to act as expected, so I'm having a problem trying to document my problem!

http://jsfiddle.net/eidsonator/he4Vc/#base

I'm trying to add a blur event handler to a input with id of "part".  My alert fires as soon as the page loads (which it shouldn't) and doesn't fire when focus is lost.  This behavior persists in chrome and in firefox (I'm coding for an internal web app, so I can ignore ie!)

```
$("#part").on('blur', alert('lost focus'));
```

I've changed the load method, and tried wrapping it in my own `$(document).ready(function() {});` as well as using `.blur()` and different versions of javacript... any clues?

Thanks!

Comment: On top of the answers below, you have the JS loading in the `head`. Change that option (left bar) in the fiddle to `onLoad`

Comment: Thanks, Jeff, however, my finished fiddle is going to have some functions in it that I'll need to have scoped differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have written a wrong syntax .see the [**docs**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for more info,and change your code to

```
 $("#part").on('blur', function(){
    //do something

    });
```

Comment: Thanks!  I've used the .on() function before, proper usage must have slipped my mind! It must be a Friday!

Comment: @eidsonator glad to help you.Happens to everyone.Good luck with the project :)

Answer (score 4):

You are calling `alert` straight away, and passing the return value of it to the `.on()` method. Instead, you need to pass a reference to a function that can be invoked when the event is received:

```
$("#part").on('blur', function () {
    alert('lost focus')
});
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/he4Vc/14/).